# Выбор кнопки для записи значения в зависимости от результата

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Проблема в следующем:
Необходимо записать значение в одну из девяти кнопок в зависимости от первой составляющей вводимой даты (дня):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var digits = textBox1.Text.Split('.');
        var digit1 = Convert.ToInt32(digits[0]);

        foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            int btnNumber = Convert.ToInt32(new String(btn.Name.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
if (digit1 == btnNumber) {
            btn.Text = digit1.ToString();
}
        }
        panel1.Visible = true;
    }
```

Не могу взять в толк, что не так с этим кодом.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(new String(btn.Name.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));`

Не только вы, я вообще не понимаю, что этот текст делает.

---
Кстати, это WPF или WinForms?

Comment: Это win form, а выбранный вами кусок берет название кнопки, допустим, "button2" или "button10", и возвращает 2 либо 10 соответственно.

Comment: А что, нельзя использовать свойство Tag?

Comment: через tag - та же проблема, switch - слишком много кода.
Можно подробнее про вариант с массивом?

Comment: Описываете массив. Элементы массива - ссылки на кнопки. Это делается все ручками, но один раз.
0й элемент массива - 1я в списке кнопка. Делаете поправку на разницу между номером элемента массива и номером кнопки, которая соответствует этому элементу и все. В итоге, чтобы кнопке button2 присвоить метку "кнп2", нужно выполнить (если массив кнопок называется, например, A): A[1].Text = "кнп2";
1й элемент - 2я кнопка.

Если, опять же, ничего с сисярпом не намудрил.

Comment: Лучше просто `Dictionary`: index -> Button. Чтобы не привязываться к магическим константам типа -1.

Comment: @VladD

Да хоть как, лишь бы структура могла связывать один к одному.